# How to use mongodb aggregate with the following data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a database with collection name "sensors" and it looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a7e1f2cf1d7cba1fe3"), "type" : "thermometer", "value" : 23, "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:31.698Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:31.698Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a7e1f2cf1d7cba1fe4"), "type" : "hygrometer", "value" : 74, "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:31.739Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:31.739Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a8e1f2cf1d7cba1fe5"), "type" : "thermometer", "value" : 25, "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.551Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.551Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a8e1f2cf1d7cba1fe6"), "type" : "hygrometer", "value" : 86, "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.584Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.584Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a9e1f2cf1d7cba1fe7"), "type" : "thermometer", "value" : 20, "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:33.554Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:33.554Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a9e1f2cf1d7cba1fe8"), "type" : "hygrometer", "value" : 84, "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:33.587Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:33.587Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

What I want to do is to query on the very last two documents, thermometer and hygrometer then check the value for each of the documents. Then based on the conditions I set using $match tag, I perform any operations I want.

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost', { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, client) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var db = client.db('mongodb');
    db.collection('sensors').aggregate(
     [
       { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
       { $limit: 1 },
       {
        $match: {"type": "hygrometer", "value": { "$gt": 60 } }
       }
     ]
   ).toArray(function(err, item) {
         if(err) console.log('error');
         if(item.length > 0) console.log('Dehumidifier ON');
         else console.log('Dehumidifier OFF');
});
```

This is the implementation for the very last data only (hygrometer) but how should I make it to check the last two documents then perform a separate operation for thermometer for example "AC ON/OFF"? I was thinking somehow make it check when item.type == "thermometer" perform something but that item.type syntax seems to not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this :

**Query 1:**

```
db.getCollection('sensors').aggregate(
    [
        { $sort: { _id: -1 } }, { $group: { _id: '$type', data: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } },
        { $project: { type: '$_id', _id: 0, lastTwo: { $slice: ["$data", 2] } } },
        { $unwind: '$lastTwo' },
        {
            $match: { $or: [{ 'type': 'hygrometer' }, { "type": "thermometer", "lastTwo.value": { "$gt": 60 } }] }
        }
    ])
```

**Query 2:**

```
  //Check the response below & If you want to group again on type, adding `$group` stage to the above query.    

  db.getCollection('sensors').aggregate(
    [
        { $sort: { _id: -1 } }, { $group: { _id: '$type', data: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } },
        { $project: { type: '$_id', _id: 0, lastTwo: { $slice: ["$data", 2] } } },
        { $unwind: '$lastTwo' },
        {
            $match: { $or: [{ 'type': 'hygrometer' }, { "type": "thermometer", "lastTwo.value": { "$gt": 60 } }] }
        }, { $group: { _id: '$type', data: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } }, { $project: { type: '$_id', _id: 0, data: 1 } }
    ])
```

In `Output 1` you can simply check whether an object with specific type exists or not and do something in code (*Vs*) in `Output 2` you've to check for type and data array is not empty.

**Sample Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a7e1f2cf1d7cba1fe3"),
    "type" : "thermometer",
    "value" : 23,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:31.698Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:31.698Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a7e1f2cf1d7cba1fe4"),
    "type" : "hygrometer",
    "value" : 74,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:31.739Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:31.739Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a8e1f2cf1d7cba1fe5"),
    "type" : "thermometer",
    "value" : 251,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.551Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.551Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a8e1f2cf1d7cba1fe6"),
    "type" : "hygrometer",
    "value" : 86,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.584Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.584Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a9e1f2cf1d7cba1fe7"),
    "type" : "thermometer",
    "value" : 20,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:33.554Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:33.554Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a9e1f2cf1d7cba1fe8"),
    "type" : "hygrometer",
    "value" : 84,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:33.587Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:33.587Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

**Output 1:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "type" : "thermometer",
    "lastTwo" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a8e1f2cf1d7cba1fe5"),
        "type" : "thermometer",
        "value" : 251,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.551Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.551Z"),
        "__v" : 0
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "type" : "hygrometer",
    "lastTwo" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a9e1f2cf1d7cba1fe8"),
        "type" : "hygrometer",
        "value" : 84,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:33.587Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:33.587Z"),
        "__v" : 0
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "type" : "hygrometer",
    "lastTwo" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a8e1f2cf1d7cba1fe6"),
        "type" : "hygrometer",
        "value" : 86,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.584Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.584Z"),
        "__v" : 0
    }
}
```

**Output 2:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "type" : "hygrometer",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "hygrometer",
            "lastTwo" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a9e1f2cf1d7cba1fe8"),
                "type" : "hygrometer",
                "value" : 84,
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:33.587Z"),
                "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:33.587Z"),
                "__v" : 0
            }
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "hygrometer",
            "lastTwo" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a8e1f2cf1d7cba1fe6"),
                "type" : "hygrometer",
                "value" : 86,
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.584Z"),
                "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.584Z"),
                "__v" : 0
            }
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "type" : "thermometer",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "thermometer",
            "lastTwo" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a8e1f2cf1d7cba1fe5"),
                "type" : "thermometer",
                "value" : 251,
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.551Z"),
                "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.551Z"),
                "__v" : 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Updates as per comments (In case if you need documents irrespective of type, as documents is always ordered), Please try this:

```
db.sensors.aggregate( [ { $sort: { _id: -1 } }, { $limit: 2 }, { $match: { $or: [{ 'type': 'hygrometer' , "value": { "$gt": 60 }}, { "type": "thermometer", "value": { "$gt": 20 } }] } } ] )
```

or make  `$slice: ["$data", 2]` to  `$slice: ["$data", 1]` from above query.

Comment: @Tony, By mistake I've filtered on thermometer but you could do $gt on hygrometer as it's just a sample, concept should be same !!

Comment: Thanks let me try it out. I actually wanna make a separate check on thermometer with $gt like $gt 25 so I guess I'll try it out!

Comment: @Tony : Your match can look like this : :>>  {
            $match: { $or: [{ 'type': 'hygrometer' , "lastTwo.value": { "$gt": 60 }}, { "type": "thermometer", "lastTwo.value": { "$gt": 25 } }] }
        }

Comment: I think my explanation wasn't clear. Because the data collection is always put in the order of thermometer, hygrometer, I wanted to check the last two documents which has a data of thermometer and a data of hygrometer. Then, with those two data, I want to check "separately" if thermometer is $gt 20 , then do sth and also check if hygromemter is $gt 60, then do sth. But your code checks for last two documents of thermometer and last two documents of hygrometer. But I only needed to check the last one document for each sensor device. It's so complicated as a mongodb beginner!

Comment: @Tony : So you wanted to check last two irrespective of type(thermometer or hygrometer) ? If that's the case, try this ::::> db.getCollection('sensors').aggregate( [ { $sort: { _id: -1 } }, { $limit: 2 }, { $match: { $or: [{ 'type': 'hygrometer' , "value": { "$gt": 60 }}, { "type": "thermometer", "value": { "$gt": 25 } }] } } ] ) or if you like the above query then you can simply change $slice: ["$data", 2] to $slice: ["$data", 1]

Comment: so it's like um no matter how many documents there are, the last two documents will be a thermometer and a hygrometer. So by only querying those two, it's always gonna be only one thermometer data and only one hygrometer data. So I'm thinking I should check if thermometer value is above 25 degrees, done. then separately also check if hygrometer value is above 60%. and if for example last sample values were 20 degrees and 80%, then the result should only output one hygrometer value with 80% and that's it.

Comment: @Tony : yes exactly, try the query from my comment above, it should work as expected, Once you're ok with it, I would update my answer as well !!

Comment: oh sweet  I think this one is what I'm exactly talking about!  "db.sensors.aggregate( [ { $sort: { _id: -1 } }, { $limit: 2 }, { $match: { $or: [{ 'type': 'hygrometer' , "value": { "$gt": 60 }}, { "type": "thermometer", "value": { "$gt": 20 } }] } } ] ) "

Comment: so with this query " db.sensors.aggregate( [ { $sort: { _id: -1 } }, { $limit: 2 }, { $match: { $or: [{ 'type': 'hygrometer' , "value": { "$gt": 60 }}, { "type": "thermometer", "value": { "$gt": 20 } }] } } ] )" after checking this, if the output only has one data, is there anyway I can check if the output's type is thermometer or hygrometer? rather than the method I used: " .toArray(function(err, item) {
         if(err) console.log('error');
         if(item.length > 0) console.log('Dehumidifier ON');
         else console.log('Dehumidifier OFF'); "sorry for asking too much..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198347/discussion-between-srinivasy-and-tony).

Answer (score 0):

After the sort, limit it to 2 and then use $or:

```
db.aggtest.aggregate([
   { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
   { $limit: 2 },
   {$match: { $or: [ {"type": "hygrometer", "value": { "$gt": 60 }}, {"type": "thermometer"} ]}}
   ])
```